# Responsive container tag with margin

Tags: html, css, media-queries, containers, margin

I am attempting to create a container that at large screen sizes contains the content in the center 940 px of the page but at smaller screen sizes simply has a small margin so the content isn't slammed against the sides of the page.

I have tried to use the calc() function to achieve this and am unsure why it breaks the margin(everything becomes left justified).

```css
.container {
 max-width: 940px; 
 margin: 0 auto;
 @media screen and (max-width: 940px) {margin: 0 calc(auto + 20px);}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

D'oh looking for padding here and no need to use the calc() function:

```css
.container {
 max-width: 940px; 
 margin: 0 auto;
 @media screen and (max-width: 940px) {padding: 0 20px);}
}
```

Comment: A little confused why the calc() function doesn't work inside of padding and would appreciate clarifications here

Answer (score 0):

try this.if this is not the case tell me.this should work for you.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
</head>
<style type="text/css">
 body{
  margin:0;
  padding: 0;

 }

 div.container{
  width:98%;
  margin: 1%;
  border:1px solid black;
  height: 650px;
 }
</style>

<body>
 <div class="container">
  
 </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This doesn't the first criteria of centering the content in the middle 940 px of the screen at large sizes

Answer (score 0):

Check this demo for what do you  want exactly and the large screen have 940px width with aligned center. Also it's work perfect in another responsive modes.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Layout CSS</title>
</head>

<style type="text/css">
body{
      margin:0;
      padding: 0;
}
.container{
      position: relative;
      display: table; /*** Used for container align center ***/
      width: 90%;
      max-width: 940px;
      margin: 2.5% auto 5% auto;
      border:1px solid black;
}
.demo_height { 
      height: 500px; /*** Demo height for box ***/
} 
</style>

<body>
<div class="container">
<div class="demo_height"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Also it's work perfect in another responsive modes.

Answer (score 0):

change this

```
<body>
<style>
.container { max-width: 940px margin: 0 auto;}
@media screen and (max-width: 940px) {
 .container {max-width:none;margin:0 20px;}
}
</style>
<div class="container" style="height:500px;background:yellow"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't really have to add to margin, just subtract from the width:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 940px) 
  {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: calc(100% - 40px);
  }
```